# Initialize rectangle in the center which is equal to 50% of the image size using Grabcut

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I try to implement ideas in the following paper: [BiCoS: A Bi-level Co-Segmentation Method for Image Classification](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vilem/iccv2011.pdf)‎ but I'm confused about the following requirement: **GrabCut here is intialized with the rectangle in the center (50% of the image size, unless noted otherwise) assigned to the foreground and the rest to background.** I don't know how to draw a rectangle in the center which takes up 50% of the image size. Please help me. I code in C++ using OpenCV library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are assuming the interested figure is bounded by a rectangle like:

```
Rect(Point(image.width/4, image.height/4), Point(image.width*3/4, image.height*3/4);
```

or the rectangle having **area** of half of the image (1/root2 size); again centered on image center point.

Then grabcut algorithm can be called within that rectangle.

If the figure is somehow close to the boundaries, then they select the rectangle by hand (supervised initiation). Since the purpose is to train the SVM with grabcut results, automation is not a must here.

Answer (score 0):

The paper should be more clear about it. Judging from the context, it probably refers to a rectangle that defines region of interest (ROI) containing a segmented object. The pixels outside of the ROI are marked as “obvious background”. As you probably know GrabCut requires you to specify areas of the image that specify obvious background pixels, possible foreground pixels, obvious foreground pixels, possible foreground pixels. All this data is be provided as parameters to [grubCut function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#grabcut) in OpenCV. Also, [here's the documentation for `cv::Rect`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect).

I don't know how authors selected the size of the rectangle. What does it mean to have a rectangle size that is 50% of the image size? It may be that the dimensions of the rectangle are equal to 1/2 of the image dimensions. Your could email the authors of the paper and ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

To select you can use Roi. However if you want to draw box or rectangle then you can use rectangle or line function.
Here is the simple code to draw rectangle box 50% size of image.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat src = imread("Desert.jpg");
    Mat src_original = src.clone();

    cv::Size sz = src.size();
    int block_size = 16;
    int x_cord_roi = sz.width/4;
    int y_cord_roi = sz.height/4;
    int width_roi = sz.width/2;
    int height_roi = sz.height/2;

    imshow("My_Win_Ori", src_original);

    Mat roi(src, Rect(x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi, width_roi, height_roi));
   // rectangle( src, Point(x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi), Point( x_cord_roi + width_roi, y_cord_roi + height_roi),
   //        Scalar(255 ), -1,8 );

    int thickness = 2;
    int lineType = 8;
    line( src, Point( x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi), Point(x_cord_roi + width_roi, y_cord_roi), Scalar( 0, 0, 0 ), thickness, lineType );
    line( src, Point( x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi), Point(x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi + height_roi), Scalar( 0, 0, 0 ), thickness, lineType );
    line( src, Point( x_cord_roi + width_roi, y_cord_roi), Point(x_cord_roi +width_roi , y_cord_roi + height_roi), Scalar( 0, 0, 0 ), thickness, lineType );
    line( src, Point( x_cord_roi, y_cord_roi + height_roi), Point(x_cord_roi + width_roi, y_cord_roi + height_roi), Scalar( 0, 0, 0 ), thickness, lineType );

    imshow("My_Win", src);
    waitKey(0);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```